# Nashorn/Javascript associative array to Java object?

Tags: javascript, java, json, nashorn

I'm trying to integrate the `JavaScript` in my Wicket project into my `TestNG` test suite. I decided to give project Nashorn a try.

Now I want to parse results from nashorn. I return an associative array from javascript, and get a `ScriptObjectMirror` as returned type.

```
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName( "nashorn" );
String content = new String( Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get( "my-funcs.js" ) ) );
Object result = engine.eval( content + ";" + script );
```

Of course, I can `JSON.stringify` the array, using more javascript script, and parse it back using `Gson` or similar libraries, but is there a more native approach to this mapping problem?

Comment: `ScriptObjectMirror` has a documented interface - http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sundar/jdk.nashorn.api/8u40/javadoc/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html

Comment: `ScriptObjectMirror` seems to implement `Map<String,Object>` - surely you can access all the key/value pairs through that?

Comment: "harmic" is right. ScriptObjectMirror is part of documented interface of Nashorn. Official API site link is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above comments, I found a relatively nice solution, using [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)

```
public static class MyResult
{
    private String prop1;
    public void setProp1(String s)
    {
        ...
    }
}

...

public MyResult getResult(String script)
{
    //ugly-but-fast-to-code unchecked cast
    ScriptObjectMirror som = (ScriptObjectMirror) engine.eval(script);    
    MyResult myResult = new MyResult();
    BeanUtils.populate(myResult, som);
    return myResult;
}
```

Comment: It will not work if you have Arrays in MyResult class. Every list in ScriptObjectMirror will be also ScriptObjectMirror object.